# Efficient and practical flood fill algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, flood-fill

I need a flood fill algorithm for using with `BufferedImage` and `Graphics2D` in Java. I do not need the simple recursive (DFS) or queue (BFS) versions of this algorithm due to their impractically. I need an efficient, practical, and salable version of this algorithm using scan lines method or any other method.

Comment: It's an O(n^2) problem.  Use the queue method.

Comment: The simple queue method has the insufficient memory problem!

Comment: I'm confused. You know you want to use the scanline method. So what do you want us to do? You already have your algorithm.

Comment: The described algorithms in Wikipedia or CodeProjet use some tricks such as "jump" that are not workable in Java!

Answer (score 1):

seems you're not the 1.st one: [Flood fill using a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783204/flood-fill-using-a-stack) 
however their solution goes for the queue. But as marked as correct, should work in case you won't find anything more efficient.