# Coloring a JPanel with pixels (Not Image)

Tags: java, colors, awt, panel, pixel

I wanted to create a frame in Java where I can draw any shape and color the shapes. I did the first part and now I have a problem in coloring the image. I have a frame which has a panel and I am drawing directly on the panel with `drawLine()` function. I want to color the shape using pixels. How to color the panel (which contains the drawing) based on pixel value?

*Note: This is not an image!! Coloring the panel. I tried many forums. But everything says about coloring an image. How to color the panel by pixels?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class colorch extends Applet implements MouseListener {
    int oldx, oldy, x, y;
    int flag = 1;
    Panel mypanel;

    public void init() {
        mypanel = new Panel();
        add(mypanel);
        addMouseListener(this);
        Panel colorpan = new Panel();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e6) { }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e7) { }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e8) {
        oldx = e8.getX();
        oldy = e8.getY();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e3) {
        x = e3.getX();
        y = e3.getY();
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.drawLine(oldx, oldy, x, y);
    }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Now I want to color inside the triangle. So I am trying to color by each pixel within this image.

Thanks.

Comment: share ur code here wat u have done for this task

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement such functionality - use [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

Here is also some code from SO - [Flood fill using a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783204/flood-fill-using-a-stack)